# prolog lists and list manipulation

Tags: prolog

i am trying to write a binary predicate to take one list, compute mod 5 for each element and then put it in another list. so far, i have done this,

```
mod5(X,L):- R = [], modhelper(R,L), write(R).  
modhelper(X,L):- memb(E,L), mod2(E,Z), addtolist(Z,X,X), modhelper(X,L).  
%Get an element from the list L.  
memb(E,[E|_]).  
memb(E,[_|V]):- memb(E,V).  
%If element is integer, return that integer mod 5 else return as is.  
mod2(N,Z):- isInt(N) -> Z is N mod 5 ; Z = N.  
%add this modified element to the output list.  
addtolist(Y,[],[Y]).  
addtolist(Y,[H|T],[H|N]):- addtolist(Y,T,N).
```

memb,mod2, addtolist work as expected but I'm doing something wrong in modhelper which I'm not able to figure out.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog:

```
mod5(X, Y) :-
    Y is X mod 5.

apply_mod5_to_list(L1, L2) :-
    maplist(mod5, L1, L2).
```

Usage:

```
?- apply_mod5_to_list([2, 4, 6, 8], L2).
L2 = [2, 4, 1, 3].

?- apply_mod5_to_list([2, 4.1, 6, 8], L2).
ERROR: mod/2: Type error: `integer' expected, found `4.1'

?- apply_mod5_to_list([2, not_number, 6, 8], L2).
ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `not_number/0' is not a function
```

You can easily modify this code if you want a slightly different behavior, e.g. if you want to tolerate non-integers (why do you want that btw?).

In case you cannot use `maplist`, you can implement it yourself, at least a more specialized version of it, e.g. something like this:

```
partition_the_list_into_first_and_rest([X | Xs], X, Xs).

% The result on an empty list is an empty list
apply_mod5_to_list([], []).

% If the input list contains at least one member
apply_mod5_to_list(L1, L2) :-
    partition_the_list_into_first_and_rest(L1, X, Xs),
    call(mod5, X, Y),
    partition_the_list_into_first_and_rest(L2, Y, Ys),
    apply_mod5_to_list(Xs, Ys).
```

To this code you can still apply a lot of syntactic simplification, which you should probably do to turn it into an acceptable homework solution...

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is for homework. I dont think i'm allowed to use maplist. i think i know what i have been doing wrong. I just have to delete the element that i have processed before i send in the the list for recursion in modhelper. however i am facing another issue. when the input is like,  
?-mod5(X,[[[12]],a]).
X=["/r"];  its interpreting [12] as "/r". How do i prevent this?

Comment: Update your question by specifying what kind of inputs you want to allow, and what should be the result on inputs that contain a non-integer.

Comment: ?-mod5(X,[a,16,b,c(5),[[12]],8]).  
X = [a,1,b,c(5),[[12]],3].  
This covers most of the inputs i guess. A non integer shall remain untouched. However, in the case of [[12]], since the ascii value of "\f" (form feed), it outputs ["\f"] when what i want it to output [[12]] as is.

Comment: Start a new question about pretty-printing lists containing the form feed character, describing how do you currently do it and what's wrong with it. This discussion does not belong to this question/answer anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kaarel. Your solution didn't quite work out. But I did find another more simple solution to the mod5 of the list problem. I still can't figure out how to take care of the form feed issue, but as you suggested i started a new question and i hope someone knows how to solve it because i have been trying for hours and can't find a soln for that.

Comment: Please post your solution here, as an answer. I'm curious to know what makes it simpler than what I provided. ;)

Comment: now if i did post the solution how would it help the others who have had to do the same homework. i learnt a lot while solving this problem and i think others should too.